# Import Wikipedia - get matching articles in different languages

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I have imported Wikipedia database dumps (`pages-articles.xml` versions) of 2 respective languages, English and Maltese.

However I need to be able to link an article from one language to another. I am under the impression that I have to import additional tables for this. Which tables do I need to import?

Thanks in advance!

Maltese db dump repository: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/mtwiki/20121012/

English db dump repository: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20121001/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That information is in [the `langlinks` table](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aLanglinks_table), so you will need to download `langlinks.sql.gz`, which is a SQL dump, not XML.

One possible issue is that those links may not be symmetric, so for example `en:A` may link to `mt:B`, but `mt:B` links to `en:C`. You'll have to decide what to do about that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create an English wiki and a Maltese wiki, and to have them link to one another.

To do this, you need to add the interlanguage prefixes for 'en' and 'mt' to the interwiki table. Here's a description of it:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Interwiki_link

You should probably remove the links to all the other languages from the articles. Otherwise they will show as junk at the bottom of a lot of articles.

P.S.: It's great to hear that you are working with the Maltese language! I really love it :)